# Resizing Image leads to Segmentation Fault OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-20.04

I am working on a OpenCV project in C++. In this I am trying to read an image and then resize the image, but on resizing the image, I get Segmentation Fault.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and install OpenCV 4.5.4 following this tutorial: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Here is the code I am using:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
 
int main()
{
  // This works: Printing out the OpenCV version
  cout << "OpenCV version : " << CV_VERSION << endl;
  cout << "Major version : " << CV_MAJOR_VERSION << endl;
  cout << "Minor version : " << CV_MINOR_VERSION << endl;
  cout << "Subminor version : " << CV_SUBMINOR_VERSION << endl;

  // This Works: Read the image using imread function
  Mat image = imread("./test_image.jpg");

  cv::Mat dst;
  // This is where it fails.
  cv::resize(image, dst, cv::Size(150,150));

  cv::namedWindow("Source", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::imshow("Source", image);

  cv::namedWindow("resize", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::imshow("resize", dst);
  waitKey(0);
  
  return 0;
}
```

I am able to show the loaded image/video frame before resizing.
Can someone please help me here as to where I am going wrong? I have been stuck on this for past 2 days, tried almost all tutorials and solutions available online, but nothing worked. Thanks.

Comment: When imread fails it will not throw an error. Before resizing, print the size of the image (width and height), which probably are 0. Or test image.empty()

Comment: I am able to imshow the image before resizing. I even tried printing the image size and that works as well. On resize, it was crashing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if the `image` is empty or not using `image.empty()`.
If that's not the case, then it's probably a issue with OpenCV. I faced the same problem with OpenCV 4.2. Updating the OpenCV version might solve the problem. OpenCV Version 4.6 perfectly worked for me.